# How can I utilise world generation through chunks (to reduce lag)

Tags: gdscript, godot-3

I've been working on a 2D pixel-styled survival game(with the Godot Game Engine), from the birds-eye view(not a side scroller like Terraria) - where the world would look like a map if zoomed out.

So far, I've used OpenSimplexNoise() to generate each map tile. This works fine, however if I wanted a large map, such as 500x500 tiles, the game would very quickly drop frames as it tries to process each tile(especially when enabling Y-sort and processing for each interactive item to be found)

Although that is no surprise, I haven't been able to find an appropriate fix or solution for this on YouTube, most tutorials only show how to generate tile-by-tile.

Could *you* please show me how to generate(and process) the world through chunks(such as Minecraft), so that when a chunk reaches a certain distance from the player, it is no longer processed?

I have also been asking ChatGPT **lol**, but it has been vague in this area when asking to expand its ideas.

I would ideally like to be able to load and offload terrain as the player explores areas.

Although I am new-ish to Godot, I have been creating simple games and learning coding theory for a while on Khan Academy(@apex.ka) and I'm eager to expand my growth and skills by your help.

Also, even if you are unfamiliar with Godot Game Engine, I could still potentially implement your logic into the engine.

Thanks in advance,
-Apex

Oh! I almost forgot -- Another simpler solution would be to ignore chunks, and just draw/process tiles that are within a certain radius of the player. The only problem there is that the Godot Game Engine(note: I'm using Godot 3 and not 4, as most of the tutorials are in 3, so whilst I'm learning I haven't upgraded) -- there is no way to hide a tile. I think Godot 4 fixes this :|

Therefore, I was thinking about separating the world into chunks of individual TileMap nodes, which then could be toggled to invisible when off the screen.

Thanks again,

Comment: It sounds like you have a plan for implementing your chunks (multiple TileMap nodes whose visibility you toggle). How have you tried implementing this so far, and where specifically do you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with
[DMGregory's comment](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/206194/how-can-i-utilise-world-generation-through-chunks-to-reduce-lag#comment375800_206194) that you should use [`TileMap`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_tilemap.html) as chunks.

You may also use a [`VisibilityNotifier2D`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_visibilitynotifier2d.html) per chunk if you need to run some code when they are out of view. By the way, note what the documentation says about `VisibilityNotifier2D`:

> **Note**: For performance reasons, VisibilityNotifier2D uses an approximate heuristic with precision determined by `ProjectSettings.world/2d/cell_size`

You can make that precise by sizing the chunks according to the project setting `world/2d/cell_size`... Or rather I should say you should tweak them together. There should be a sweet spot for the chunk size (too small and the logic that hide/disable them is running too often, too big and they require too much processing). So use experimentation and profiling.

You can use a secondary [`Thread`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_thread.html) to create the `TileMap`s and use [`call_deferred`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-call-deferred) to add them to the scene tree (`call_deferred("add_child", tile_map)`).

About the generation of the tiles, yes it is tile by tile, but there are other opportunities for optimization. Look for anything you can cache/memoize in your code. In fact, if you plan to remove chunks that are away from the player, I remind you that removing them from the scene tree (`remove_child`) is not the same as deleting them (`queue_free`) so you can have a cache of recently removed chunks ready to be added back... And going down that rabbit hole, you might implement an object pool for chunks, so instead of creating a new chunk from scratch you might reuse one that was removed.